# Canceling a CoroutineScope using CoroutineContext#cancelChidren instead of CoroutineScope.cancel

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In an Android application, I have a scenario where I want to cancel a `CoroutineScope` when I navigate to another page. Still, I want `CoroutineScope` to be usable after the user returns to that page. The problem is calling [cancel()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/cancel.html) on `CoroutineScope`, makes the `CoroutineScope` unusable since it gets canceled. I researched a bit and found out that there is a method for `CoroutineContext` named [cancelChidlren()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/cancel-children.html) which as written in the documentation:

> Cancels all children jobs of this coroutine using Job.cancel() for all of them with an optional cancellation cause. Unlike Job.cancel() on this job as a whole, the state of this job itself is not affected.

Is it a good idea to use `coroutineScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()` instead of `coroutineScope.cancel()` for canceling the coroutine scope? Can it cause problems (i.e. memory leaks) for not calling `cancel()` on a `CoroutineScope` and only using `cancelChildren()`?

Comment: What preventing you from cancelling the job on pause and recreating it on resume?

Comment: Well, in my case, coroutines are handled by custom components that do not know anything about the lifecycle of activity/fragment, and Their lifecycle is get handled by a `StateHandler` class, And I want them to stay this way. Maybe I should handle their lifecycle from that `StateHandler` (i.e. add onPause and onStop, etc for them)?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to stop your job when the activity is stopped, then yes, you should use the `cancelChildren()` method.  In the destroy your should call the `cancel()` method.

And IMO I think you wont have any problem like memory leaks, etc.  I am using this approach in the Presenters and they are working properly.

Comment: So in the end I have to call `cancel()`? calling only `cancelChildren()` is not enough?

Comment: Call cancel() when the activity is destroyed, if the activity is only stopped, then use cancelChildren()